# Intermittent Bean Currently in Creation Exception

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

We have an application that we deliver via docker in a tomcat 8.5 alpine image. 99% of the time it loads fine, but very rarely we instead get the following error

```
Error creating bean with name 'SettingsHome': Bean with name 'SettingsHome' \
has been injected into other beans [SettingsService] in its raw version as \
part of a circular reference, but has eventually been wrapped. This means that \
said other beans do not use the final version of the bean. This is often the \
result of over-eager type matching - consider using 'getBeanNamesOfType' with \
the 'allowEagerInit' flag turned off, for example.
```

When this happens we have tried rebooting the host, performing a docker image prune and re-pulling, nuking any volumes and rebuilding but nothing ever works. We usually end up having to re-install the OS. Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

Comment: This happens at random because order of instantiation of beans is not strict. It is hard to solve your problem without access to app. I suggest inspecting all beans dependency on `SettingsHome`. Especially non declarative.

Comment: If its not strict, why can I not get past this issue by re deploying the docker image?

Comment: It is depends on multiple factors, but they not random. They just extremely hard to predict (like addresses in memory). docker images are well isolated, so you just get same values again. You can try to shake system by changing amount of memory for example, but there is no guarantee it will work. I suggest you to fix root problem.